# How can you find an underlying table in MVC from the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to know how to find the underlying tables for Models in MVC.  I am working in an MVC asp.net application with a new team and need to find out which tables are underlying the Models.  Is there a way to find these in VS?  The model names do not necessarily correspond to a table in the database.  So I am looking to find which table (or tables) are references by a model.

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming your talking about database "tables". MVC has absolutely nothing to do with db "tables".

Comment: You can use `Entity Framework` to do this. Simply use database or code first approach for underlying the tables with models. I believe, this is what you are looking for,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Entity Framework for data access? Code first? Model first? Database first? If you're using Code First, and the tables aren't named by model builder conventions, try looking in your context class for a method with the signature:

```
override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

This method will likely contain configuration that maps the models to unconventional names. IE:

```
HasMany(u => u.Friends)
.WithMany()
.Map(u => {
    u.ToTable("Friends");
});
```